# Rectangular box as input value in ionic form

Tags: ionic-framework

I created a login form using ionic4 which yields me a floating text row to enter the login credentials.

```
<ion-content>
<ion-title class="ion-text-center" >Login</ion-title>
<ion-item>
<ion-label position="floating" >Email Id</ion-label>
<ion-input type="text" ></ion-input>
</ion-item>

<ion-item>
<ion-label position="floating" >Password</ion-label>
<ion-input type="password" ></ion-input>
</ion-item>
<ion-text color="tertiary"><h6>Forgot Password?</h6></ion-text>

<div class="login-btn">
<ion-button class="login-button" expand="full">Login</ion-button>
</div>

<div class="not-a-member">
<ion-text>Not a member yet? </ion-text><ion-text color="tertiary"> Sign-Up</ion-text>
```

I want the rectangular input box in the form instead of floating text row.
[image]

Comment: Try to remove: `position="floating"`  attribute from your `ion-label` tag

Comment: hi@Najamussaqib thanks for your response, I tried this but it gives me only to input the value, but  i want a rectangular box input

Comment: you have to create in manually.

Comment: i have completely no idea about that in case of ionic. can you help me with some ounces of code

Comment: Also share your code so i can guide you .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this code:

```
<div  style="margin: 10px;">
      <ion-input type="email" placeholder="Email" [(ngModel)]="email" style="text-align: center; border: skyblue solid 0.5px;"></ion-input>
    </div>

    <div  style="margin: 10px;">
      <ion-input type="password"  placeholder="Password"  [(ngModel)]="password" style="text-align: center; border: skyblue solid 0.5px;"></ion-input>
    </div>
```